# Bootstrap date picker not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I used the following code and its not working .

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head runat="server">
    <title>Test Zone</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Css/datepicker.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">    </script>

   <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#pickyDate').datepicker({
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
        });
    });
</script>
```

and inside body I have called using the id "pickydate". I could not get the proper bootstrap datepicker, though i added the css and js files to my file. what should be the cause of its not working.. let me be guided..

```
 <body>
<div id="testDIV">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="hero-unit">
            <input  type="text" placeholder="click to show datepicker"  id="pickyDate"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: bootstrap Datepicker Not working properly]

Comment: Do you check if the library file loaded property?

Comment: how to check it? If so, how should i load it?

Comment: on the developer tool, any 404 appear on the console?

Comment: no i did not get any single error

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to connect data-picker [css](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/tree/master/dist/css)

Comment: but the question show he include ```<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Css/datepicker.css" /> ``` so I can't be sure if no css for datapicker

Comment: yes i included the css and js files and it doesnt show me a bug in console..!

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided is correct. I think you might have provided incorrect URL for Datepicker javascript file or CSS file. This is the working example for your question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test Zone</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#pickyDate').datepicker({
                format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="testDIV">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="hero-unit">
                <input type="text" placeholder="click to show datepicker" id="pickyDate" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Also in the question it seems that the date picker is put inside a modal dialogue. In that case please verify that the z-index of the date picker is greater that the z-index of modal popup. If z-index of the modal popup is greater than z-index of date picker, the date picker will go behind modal popup.

Comment: What I mean is you might have provided the incorrect path for the files datepicker.css or bootstrap-datepicker.js. Please make sure that the path you have provided for them is correct. Does the above code snippet works fine for you?

Comment: In the question it seems that the date picker is put inside a modal dialogue. In that case please verify that the z-index of the date picker is greater that the z-index of modal popup. If z-index of the modal popup is greater than z-index of date picker, the date picker will go behind modal popup.

Comment: yes i have given it inside the bootstrap modal only

Comment: how should i verify the z-index of modal popup and date-picker

Comment: Please look at the z-index of the modal popup and the z-index of date picker. z-index of date picker should be greater than that of modal popup. just inspect the element and search for the style z-index to find that out

Comment: can you give a z-index example along with the answer above , which i shall provide..

Comment: Please provide a  z-index: 3000; for date picker and z-index: 1050; for modal popup. Please look into this  code (https://codepen.io/Sinetheta/pen/Ftjwi) aswell